# How to process a bunch of text files all at once with the source command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of text files where I keep all my stored procedures, table definitions, insertion statements and things like that. If I had, let's say, 5 files, then I would have to type out all 5 lines of code like so:

```
\. C:/project/1.sql
\. C:/project/2.sql
\. C:/project/3.sql
\. C:/project/4.sql
\. C:/project/5.sql
```

Well, I could get around this and make another text file calling it something like **main.sql** where I would put all those 5 lines of code and if I wanted to execute those 5 files, I would only have to type this simple line:

```
\. C:/project/main.sql
```

But the problem with this is that if I move all those files to another location or simply rename the folder where those are stored, I would have to change the path string in all those 5 lines. For instance, If I were to change the location of the folder **project** to something like **projects/application1/**, I would have to retype virtually the whole thing:

```
\. C:/projects/application1/1.sql
\. C:/projects/application1/2.sql
\. C:/projects/application1/3.sql
\. C:/projects/application1/4.sql
\. C:/projects/application1/5.sql
```

Now, the question, as you may have already guessed, is how to save all this trouble so that if I want to move the files, all I have to change is one line of code? I tried something like this but it didn't work out:

```
SET @PATH = 'C:/projects/application1/';

\. SELECT CONCAT(@PATH, 1.sql)
\. SELECT CONCAT(@PATH, 2.sql)
\. SELECT CONCAT(@PATH, 3.sql)
\. SELECT CONCAT(@PATH, 4.sql)
\. SELECT CONCAT(@PATH, 5.sql)
```

Comment: Why not write a Java application？

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote a program, maybe help you:)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Author: NobodyElse
 * Date: 13-4-17
 * Time: 11:00 AM
 * Description: bulk import mysql
 */
public class ImportUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage:" + ImportUtil.class.getSimpleName() + " filePath dbName dbUser dbPass");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        String filePath = args[0];
        String dbName   = args[1];
        String dbUser   = args[2];
        String dbPass   = args[3];

        File path = new File(filePath);
        if (!path.exists() || !path.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(filePath + " not exist OR isn't a directory");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        else {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                String fileName = file.getPath();
                if (fileName.endsWith(".sql")) {
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    execute(fileName, dbName, dbUser, dbPass);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ALL DONE!");
    }

    public static void execute(String fileName, String dbName, String dbUser, String dbPass){

        String mysqlPath = "cmd /c D:\\Program\" \"Files\\MySQL\\MySQL\" \"Server\" \"5.5\\bin\\mysql.exe";

        StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer(mysqlPath);
        cmd.append(" -u").append(dbUser);
        cmd.append(" -p").append(dbPass).append(" ");
        cmd.append(dbName).append("<").append(fileName);

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's cool, but I was actually looking for an easier solution within the realm of MySQL. Thanks though.